# getting object in each element in vector

Tags: c++

Is there a way for an iterator to return an object in each element of a C++ Standard Library vector?

I have this code:

```
struct mystruct {
  int field1;
}

int DoSomethingWithMyStruct(mystruct& a);

std::vector<mystruct> myVector;
std::vector<mystruct>::iterator it;

mystruct s1,s2, temp;
s1.field1=1;
s2.field1=2;

for (it=myVector.begin();it!=myVector.end();it++)
{
   //I want to call DoSomethingWithMyStruct, so I have to pass in mystruct object.
   //can I use iterator to get the object of each element in myVector without having to create a temporary mystruct object and pass it in?
   //I'm looking for an easier way than having to do this:
   temp.field1 = it->field1;
   DoSomethingWithMyStruct(temp);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as what the others said, you can do this instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), DoSomethingWithMyStruct);
```

It's short and succinct. No need of manual loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
DoSomethingWithMyStruct(*it);
```

Comment: `temp` is a `mystruct`, not an `int`.

Comment: @Tomalak: Derp. (In case you didn't understand that due to cultural differences, that's what someone says when they feel stupid)

Comment: I got it! I doubt that there are too many cultural differences between us. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just dereference the iterator, surely:

```
std::vector<mystruct>::iterator it, end;
for (it = myVector.begin(), end = myVector.end(); it != end; ++it) {
   DoSomethingWithMyStruct(*it);
}
```

Or am I missing something here...?

Going further, there are other ways to iterate. You could use `BOOST_FOREACH` or C++0x ranged-for to simplify the loop. You could also use an algorithm like `std::for_each` to remove it entirely!

---

<sup>(Remember that `it->field1` is like `(*it).field1`, so you're already doing this... even though you're going on to make your code more complicated than is necessary afterwards!)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just simply dereference your iterator. `*it`, and you get a `mystruct`. They behave like pointers in this regard.

But in the case if you wonder how to iterate over all fields of all elements of a vector, where the elements are polymorphic; e.g. `std::vector<Base*>`, it's a bit more difficult. Since C++ doesn't have reflection that would make this possible (semi)automatically, you need to do it manually. Something similar to the Visitor Pattern comes to mind.

Answer (score -3):

1. You have not populated `myVector`
2. Could make code more efficent like this

   `std::vector<mystruct>::const_iterator theEnd;`

   `for (it=myVector.begin();it!=theEnd;++it)`

   *Notice the position of the ++*
3. I think that `&(*it)` should work.

Comment: `myVector` is almost certainly there for exposition, and is filled in the real code. Efficacy is a maybe, but your solution is incorrect, only `(*it)` is needed. I didn't downvote you but I suspect whoever did thought similarly *and won't forget to comment in the future...*